# jQuery url is not swapped around on a web server

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Okay so here's the problem.

```
<a>
```

Tag on the website has a href of

```
/news-features/8/news-headlines/103818/these-pupils-deserve-better
```

and of course the domain in the beginning let's say it is:

http://www.webserver.com/

Therefore the whole link is

http://www.webserver.com/news-features/8/news-headlines/103818/these-pupils-deserve-better

However, it should be:

http://www.oldham-chronicle.co.uk/news-features/8/news-headlines/103818/these-pupils-deserve-better

So it is linked to the website information is taken from.

My JQuery function is

```
var base = "http://www.oldham-chronicle.co.uk/";
$('a').each(function(index, element) {
  element.href = element.href.replace("http://dev.liveoldham.com/", base);
});
```

Which locally works fine as it gives me the correct link however the same code on a webserver gives me:

/news-features/8/news-headlines/103818/these-pupils-deserve-better
[image]

Now I am not sure what is the fault, is it the .htaccess and it's rewrite rule or is it something else?

Comment: Check your console log for any errors. Also try to hard refresh the page to clear the cache.

Comment: how do you hard refresh the page in google chrome?

Comment: Ctrl + F5 or hold control and hit the refresh icon

Comment: well, it's funny my link in console is correct but when I hover over the link it's missing : so it's http// instead of http://

Comment: however I had to change function to this? var base = "http://www.oldham-chronicle.co.uk/";
$('a').each(function(index, element) {
  element.href = element.href.replace("dev.liveoldham.com/", base);
}); but still missing the ":"

Comment: Does the original link actually have the the webserver part on it or is it a link like `href="/news...."`  If the latter then there won't be anything to replace.  You could do a check to see if it starts with the `http://`, if it does do a replace, otherwise do a prepend